# Generics<T> that accept String, &str and primitive value

Tags: rust

I apologize in advance as this may somewhat dumb question.
I was trying to create the function that simply return the bool result of
whether the given value is prime number or not.

I wanted the function to both accept the String, &str and primitive value.
Is there anyway that I can make this possible.

```
pub fn prime<T>(val: T) -> bool 
    where T: ToPrimitive {
    let val = val.to_i64().unwrap();
    for i in 2..=val {
        if val % i == 0 {
            return false;
        }
        
        if i*i >= val {
            break;
        }
    }
    true
}
```

Comment: What is `ToPrimitive`? Where does it come from? And what is `to_i64`?

Comment: it is a trait from num crate that  I am using for converting T to i64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned with performance, leave it as is. You are already accepting all integer types. Conversion from strings should happen elsewhere. (as already mentioned by the other answers)

That said, to actually fulfill your request, here is a horribly inefficient but simple solution to your problem :)

```rust
pub fn prime<T>(val: T) -> bool
where
    T: ToString,
{
    let val: u64 = val.to_string().parse().unwrap();
    for i in 2..val {
        if val % i == 0 {
            return false;
        }

        if i * i >= val {
            break;
        }
    }
    true
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", prime(17));
    println!("{:?}", prime("17"));
    println!("{:?}", prime(String::from("17")));
}
```

```
true
true
true
```

---

On a more serious note ... your own solution and all of the answers convert the input into another type.

If you skip that and instead use the given type directly, you could potentially get a speed boost.

For that to work, though, I had to switch from `i * i >= val` to `..=val.sqrt()`.

```rust
pub fn prime<T>(val: T) -> bool
where
    T: num::PrimInt + num::integer::Roots,
{
    let two = T::one() + T::one();
    for i in num::range_inclusive(two, val.sqrt()) {
        if val % i == T::zero() {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", prime(17));
}
```

```
true
```

---

As a further note, you could rewrite the entire `for` loop with the `all` iterator method:

```rust
pub fn prime<T>(val: T) -> bool
where
    T: num::PrimInt + num::integer::Roots,
{
    let two = T::one() + T::one();
    num::range_inclusive(two, val.sqrt()).all(|i| val % i != T::zero())
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", prime(17));
}
```

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted the function to both accept the String, &str and primitive value.
> Is there anyway that I can make this possible.

You'd have to create your own trait to unify the feature: while Rust has grown the [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) trait, in the stdlib currently it's only used for faillible `integer -> integer` conversions (e.g. i64 to u8). `String -> integer` conversions remain on the older [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) trait, and it's unclear that there's any plan to migrate.

I would agree with @cameron1024 though, doing this conversion in the callee increases the complexity without making much sense, if the callee takes a string I would expect *it* to handle and report validation / conversion errors to the source of the values. The prime of a string doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do you really want to be able to check if strings are prime? You probably don't want someone to be able to write `prime("hello")`.

Assuming you're fine with numbers, I'd just use `Into<u128>` as the trait bound:

```rust
fn prime<T: Into<u128>>(t: T) -> bool {
  let val = t.into();

  // rest of the logic
}
```

So what about strings and signed integers?

IMO, you should convert these at the call-site, which allows for better error handling, rather than just `unwrap()`:

```rust
/// strings
prime("123".parse()?);
prime(String::from("123").parse()?);

/// signed ints
prime(u128::try_from(123i8)?);
```

This way, you can use `?` to correctly handle errors, and make `prime` panic-free.

---

If you really want to not have to convert at the callsite, you could use a custom trait:

```rust
trait TryIntoU128 {
  type Error;
  fn try_into_u128(self) -> Result<u128, Self::Error>;
}
```

Then you could implement this on various types:

```rust
impl TryIntoU128 for String {
  type Error = ParseIntError;
  fn try_into_u128(self) -> Result<u128, Self::Error> {
    self.parse()
  }
}

// etc
```

Then you can use this trait bound for your `prime` function instead

Comment: I disagree with using `u128` for everything, as the question already limited the size to `i64`. `u128` is way slower on most architectures.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is .. leave it as is? Because his current implementation can already accept most integer types.

Comment: Sure, u128 is a tradeoff between flexibility and performance. As for the current implementation, I'm not sure I agree with `ToPrimitive` as a trait bound. I don't think a prime-checking function should accept floats, when it's just going to panic in the body if you pass one

Comment: I tend to agree with you. I'd go with `Into<u64>`, then. But I understand your point.